# date-fns isSameWeek not working as expected

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns

I'm new with `date-fns` but intuitively, I would expect this to be `true`:

```
isSameWeek(new Date(2021, 11, 11), new Date(2021, 11, 12))
```

But it actually is `false`

I must be missing something?

It looks like Thursday seems to be the start of the week because this is true:

```
isSameWeek(new Date(2021, 11, 12), new Date(2021, 11, 18))
```

EDIT: When I do this

```
isSameWeek(new Date(2021, 11, 11), new Date(2021, 11, 12), {weekStartsOn: 1})
```

It now is true... I'm confused.

Comment: And even when setting `weekStartsOn` to 0 (which docs say it is default anyway) it still results in the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The months start at `0` being January.

So `11` is December.

December 11 is a Saturday, the 12th is Sunday (start of the next week).
So they are not in the same week.

December 12 is Sunday, December 18th is the Saturday of the same week.
So they are in the same week.

Comment: Oh my God. I'm dumb. Classic mistake. I'm gonna pretend like I've been writing code in Matlab my whole life where indexes start at 1.